# Where can I see on Merrill Edge the sum of the dividends and distributions that were from a foreign country or U.S. possession in a given year?

Tags: united-states, taxes, dividends, international

When preparing my US taxes, I need to indicate the sum of my dividends and distributions that were from a foreign country or U.S. possession in a given year. E.g., in TurboTax:

[image]

Where can I see on Merrill Edge the sum of the dividends and distributions that was from a foreign country or U.S. possession in a given year?

---

Fidelity gives me that number (= sum of the dividends and distributions that was from a foreign country or U.S. possession in a given year) in their 1099 consolidated form (Total Foreign Income):

[image]

so I wonder where it is on the Merrill Edge statements. Or do I have to manually compute the sum of all the foreign dividends myself from the Merrill Edge 1099?

[image]

Comment: And again you're asking here instead of asking Merrill...

Comment: @littleadv why not ask other Merrill customers?

Comment: https://old.reddit.com/r/tax/comments/11scsjg/where_can_i_see_on_merrill_edge_the_sum_of_the/ Same question.

Comment: @MichaelA I used to mention crossposts in the question details but some people didn't like it so I stopped.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it would be better addressed directly to product support.

Comment: @keshlam that's not a reason to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is on Merrill Edge no convenient place to see the sum of the dividends and distributions that were from a foreign country or U.S. possession in a given year. One has to compute the sum oneself. (GPT-4V 0613 wasn't able to compute the sum when I tried given the bank statement and the prompt "What's the total amount of foreign dividends?").